# MongoDB How to Convert propery values from int to string for all documents?

Tags: mongodb

I am very new to MongoDB, I have existing documents with property name of "duns_number" its values are currently Int32, How do I convert the "duns_number" values to String?

Here is what I have so far but this doesn't convert the values to string.

```
db.getCollection('ds_masterlist').update({"duns_number": { $type: "int" }, { $set: {"duns_number": { $type: "string" }} }})
```

I tried this as well,

```
db.ds_masterlist.find( { 'duns_number' : { $type : "int" } } ).forEach( function (x) {   
  x.duns_number = new String(x.duns_number); 
  db.ds_masterlist.save(x);
});
```

However it is converting each digit of the duns_number

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

```
db.ds_company_masterlist.find( { 'duns_number' : { $type : "int" } } ).forEach( function (x) {   
  x.duns_number= ""+x.duns_number; // convert field to string
  db.ds_company_masterlist.save(x);
});
```

This resolves my problem.

also this one incase not applied to all records,

```
db.ds_masterlist.update(
  {  },
  [{ $set: { duns_number: { $toString: "$duns_number" } } }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

Thank You